# Wamp server installed on windows server 2008 r2 not accessible through WAN

Tags: wamp, windows-server-2008-r2

Objective: make contents of wamp 2.5 (www) directory accessible to web users,      installed on windows server 2008r2 data center (with evaluation keys.)

progress so far : i am able to view the directory in the LAN but but am unable to access it with my public ip.

Have changed listen in httpd.conf to my servers local ip 
added inbound rules for port 1433,80 and 8081 in windows firewall          (seems to be on 80)
port forwarded my router to port 1433,80 and 8081

and still cannot access contents of the www directory in wamp publicly 
been at this for a while now could someone please tell me what i am missing?
Thanks!